# Use Javascript to call and return a value when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript

I am trying to accomplish the following and I don't know why I am struggling.  Create a new fiddle that contains a button with the text "x2" and the number 1 like this:

1
x2

Use Javascript to make it so that each time the button is clicked, the number above the x2 button will double. Send me the link to the fiddle.

Here is what I have thus far.  I know I am targeting the button via JS but I cannot figure out how to return the updated value when the x2 button is clicked.

```
<p id="counter">1</p>
<button onclick="calc()">x2</button>
<script>
function calc() {
    var element = document.getElementById("counter") *2;
    return counter.innerHTML = element;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at what this code is doing:

```
var element = document.getElementById("counter") *2;
```

You are multiplying an element by two, you are NOT reading the text.

You want to use `innerHTML` or `textContent`. That returns a string, so you want to use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  Why does this only work on jsfiddle when I include the JS in my HTML file using the <script> tags?  When I add the code to the JavaScript module, the code does not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/cbadrew00/8z1prepf/#update

Answer (score 1):

Don't return, nothing will read your return. Put it back into `counter` element. Also, `document.getElementById("counter") *2` will give you `NaN`, since you are multiplying an `Element` object by a number; you need to work on `.textContent` value, which is a string (and will be automatically converted to a number when done arithmetics to).

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  Why does this only work on jsfiddle when I include the JS in my HTML file using the <script> tags?  When I add the code to the JavaScript module, the code does not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/cbadrew00/8z1prepf/#update

Comment: The reason is the fact that normally JavaScript is put into the `<head>` tag. Because JavaScript is executed as soon as it is found, at the time when it is run your `counter` does not exist yet. You can avoid the issue by putting the javascript below the button (as you presumably did), or having it attached to the `load` event (see examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) ).

Answer (score 1):

This is what you will need to do:

The `calc()` function needs to address the `innerHTML` of the element that changes. Then a multiplication of the same `innerHTML` needs to be assigned to that, but it needs to be converted to a number first. There’s nothing else—no `return` statement or anything.

This snippet contains the code to do it (hidden, because spoiler, although it’s too late anyways):

```js
function calc(){
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML=Number(document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML)*2;
}
```

```html
<p id="counter">1</p>
<button onclick="calc()">x2</button>
```

Comment: It is good form to avoid giving straight-out answers to people who are obviously doing homework, as it is promoting academic dishonesty. Instead, try to explain what they are doing wrong, so they can learn from it and do the exercise themselves.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  Why does this only work on jsfiddle when I include the JS in my HTML file using the <script> tags?  When I add the code to the JavaScript module, the code does not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/cbadrew00/8z1prepf/#update

Comment: And yes, I am doing homework, but I am also trying to get an understanding of the syntax.  I NEED to learn this stuff

Comment: Your syntax is fine. If there was something that was off in your syntax, we would have mentioned it.

Comment: @DrewTuzson Hm… if you look at the JavaScript console in your browser it says that `calc` wasn’t defined. You can fix this by selecting the “No wrap—in <head>” option in JSFiddle on the left and putting the JS into the JS field. Basically like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8z1prepf/3/).

Comment: Thank you!  I am not sure what the no wrap in <head> option does, but it worked.  The quick responses from this community was incredible.

Comment: A wrapping in JavaScript would be a function that works like an event handler for the `load` or the `DOMContentLoaded` events (depending on option). “No wrapping—in <head>” means that the JS goes into the `<head>` of the document and the other one means that it goes into the `<body>`. But this is not the right place to explain it in detail…

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function calc() {
    var newvalue = parseInt(document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML) * 2;
    alert(newvalue);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  Why does this only work on jsfiddle when I include the JS in my HTML file using the <script> tags?  When I add the code to the JavaScript module, the code does not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/cbadrew00/8z1prepf/#update

Comment: It works in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8z1prepf/4/
BUT you have to select 'No wrap' in the select box on the corner top left.
Because, you need to manipulate the DOM :

        document.getElementById("counter")

AND the function calc must be declared in the global scope.

Comment: so the no wrap option allows me to declare global scope?  I am sorry for the noob questions.  I have been neglecting js for far too long and I really need to start learning this

Comment: To understand why it doesn't works look to the jsfiddle generated source code ! :) (Inspect the result with F12) And try your code with no wrap and with onLoad. Search for your calc() function and you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` actually returns string rather than number, so to convert it into number we need to call `parseInt()`:

```
<p id="counter">1</p>
<button onclick="calc()">x2</button>
<script>
   function calc() {
      var element = parseInt(document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML) * 2;
   return counter.innerHTML = element;
}
```